# How to get id of last inserted row with ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting identity row value using ADO.NET Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831894/getting-identity-row-value-using-ado-net-entity)

This is my example code:

```
var klienciToAdd = new klienci();
klienciToAdd.nazwa = collection["nazwa"];
klienciToAdd.miejscowosc = collection["miejscowosc"];

_db.AddToklienci(klienciToAdd);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use klienciToAdd.id after calling SaveChanges() method.