# Database-independent way to retrieve generated id in ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net

Is there a way in ADO.NET to retrieve the auto-generated ID after executing an INSERT-statement? I know about `SELECT @@IDENTITY` for Sql Server and `SELECT last_insert_id()` for MySQL, but what I need is a database-independent way to retrieve the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think a way exists, because the command to get last inserted id is vendor specific. What you can do is to incorporate the query to get last inserted id in your main query (which I understand is not what you want) and then write a C# function to read it irrespective of your db (without relying on specific ADO.NET type but on the methods specified on interface `IDbDataReader` or `IDbCommand`)

Or else you will have to rely on some ORM solution like Entity Framework which will handle all this for you saving you from the hassle of manually getting last inserted id, though the implementation will be very db specific. You can see a nice discussion on that here:

[getting identity row value using ADO.NET Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831894/getting-identity-row-value-using-ado-net-entity)

You can see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx) which will give you some insight on directly accessing the records relying on dataadapters (but I dont like it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder why ADO.NET, which is a database abstraction layer, does not abstract the way to get the generated id.

Comment: @Florian because ADO is not the one who does the job of inserting and updating, its the underlying db. But I'm also wondering why ADO interfaces haven't forced its customers to write a getlastinsertedid function!

Comment: Yes, too bad. I don't think there are technical reasons because in JDBC and PDO this functionality exists.

Comment: @Florian that new news to me! JDBC must be better than ADO then! will try it! But I don't like the fact that Java doesn't have C# `using`s which is very important for clean code in a layer that deals with disposables!